# Mode rewrite code not working

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've the following code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]

# add a trailing slash    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

What I wanted to do want to remove the .PHP extension and add leading slash into the URL it does both that code removed the .php extension and also add the leading slash but then it throw the following error

```
Not Found
The requested URL /Parties.php was not found on this server.
```

my URL is below

```
http://localhost/legalHQWithNewAddressTable/legalHQ/public/admin/Parties/
```

what should I do to get this working.

Any Idea?

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess and do you have other rules too?

Comment: @anubhava it is stored in the same location I mean in admin folder I got it working but it is not loading css and javascript files I've the following changes `RewriteBase /legalHQWithNewAddressTable/legalHQ/public/admin/` and it started working but again issue is loading css and javascript files

Comment: @anubhava I do not have any other rules... what I going to do now is going to make this thing again from scratch hoping this time I would be able to make it working... :(

Comment: So you're not getting `The requested URL /Parties.php was not found on this server` error any more?

Comment: What is an example of 404 css path? Also what is correct css URL?

Comment: Yes @anubhava that is right but again the issue is loading the css and java files

Comment: @anubhava everything is in the same folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58239/discussion-between-anubhava-and-usman-sharif-amjad-khan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of these 2 fixes:

1. Just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/legalHQWithNewAddressTable/legalHQ/public/admin/`.
2. You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/legalHQWithNewAddressTable/legalHQ/public/admin/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current URL.

Answer (score 1):

first you need to add the following

```
RewriteBase /legalHQWithNewAddressTable/legalHQ/public/admin
```

and then add the following tag in your head section of html page

```
<base href="/legalHQWithNewAddressTable/legalHQ/public/admin/" />
```

try that and let me know if that works